# partition and rpartiton getting TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, partition

I'm getting this error when I try to run the script.

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Here is the script:

```
containerFile = open((tmpImageDirectory+"container.rvbr"), "r")
containedString = containerFile.read()
containerFile.close()
containedFiles = containedString .partition[","]
```

container.rvbr contains a string with several comas.
If execute this `str(conatinedString)` I get this `<type 'str'>`, so it's a string.I wonder if somebody can explain this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parentheses rather than square brackets to call a method:

```
containedFiles = containedArray.partition(",")
```

Furthermore, you probably want to do `split` rather than `partition`: `partition` will keep the commas in the resulting tuple, even though those commas are not in fact files:

```
"hello,world".partition(",")
# ('hello', ',', 'world')
"hello,world".split(",")
# ['hello', 'world']
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry for that stupid question. I did not search for type error because of I did not get syntax error. split() function solved my next problem - to get rid of comas.

Answer (score 0):

```
containedFiles = containedString .partition(",")
```

not

```
containedFiles = containedString .partition[","]
```

use parentheses when you want to call a method.